# XSL unexpected token $ error exception

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am a newbie to XSL programming. Could you please help me in solving this issue?

Is it possible to combine and fetch the values of two xsl:variable
Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="path1" select="//path1"/>
<xsl:variable name="path2" select="//path2/value"/>
```

Then combine them using:

```
<xsl:value-of select ="$path1/$path2"/>
```

I want to fetch the value from path1 by combining the result from path2
If I use the above code I get unexpected token $ error

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: No, that's not the correct way. Be clearer in describing what you want and maybe we can find a solution for that.

Comment: @empo: I think it's clear what he wants. Text value of `//path1` is some element name (say `foo`), text value of `//path2/value` is some other element name (say `bar`) and the element given by the second name under element of the first name should be found, i.e. he wants to find `foo/bar` (and get it's value).

Comment: Very unclear/bad question. In particular this sentence: "I want to fetch the value from path1 by combining the result from path2". What is the set of nodes you need to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're possibly looking to do

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($path1,$path2)" />
```

It's worth pointing out here that you're not actually storing the paths in those variables, but the nodes that those paths point to. i.e. `$path1` does not contain `//path1`, but the value of whatever that node contains.

If you actually wanted the text `'//path1//path2/value'`, then you need to define your path variables with

```
<xsl:value-of select="path1" select="'//path1'" />
<xsl:value-of select="path2" select="'//path2/value'" />
```

(note the extra `'` that indicates it's a text value rather than an xpath). The same `<xsl:value-of` statement above will give you output of `'//path1//path2/value'` in this case.

If you actually want the contents of the `//path1//path2/value` node, it's a lot trickier, and it's more than likely there's a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do.